# One class classification for images

Tags: computer-vision, one-class-classification

Say You have thousands of images of cat, like this: (https://web.archive.org/web/20150703060412/http://137.189.35.203/WebUI/CatDatabase/catData.html). 
You wish to build a system that can look at a image and say - if the image is that of cat or not.

```
 What are the (if any) techniques to build such a model with a descent accuracy?
```

PS1: The key challenge in this problem is to see that "what is not a cat" is a huge universe - every image in this world that is not of cat qualifies for it. 
Formulating this problem as a binary classification is not good since it is near impossible to collect a "comprehensive" dataset of "what is not a cat". (if you do so, your model will be as good as your dataset of "what is not a cat")

PS2: Such a setting is called "One class classification"

Comment: If you don't have anything to compare with the classification result will say that is similar to a cat with a high percentage because you have trained the system to know what a cat is. If you need to have a high accuracy then you need to train other classes in your system, of course, the result of "Non classified" will be the one that doesn't match with any of those.

Comment: Also, binary classification problems where the negative class is a lot bigger are not uncommon. Of course, your classifier won't have perfect accuracy, but other than that I don't see the problem.

Comment: @BrankVictoria: pls read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification

Comment: @TA: I have data of only one class! (images of cats)

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is to use One-Class SVM, which essentially is doing outlier detection.
In practice you can first apply a pre-trained CNN to extract a meaningful compact representation of the images and then use those vectors as input to a One-Class SVM. Everything non-cat will be an outlier!